# WebDriver Java class to run on Safari 10 on El Capitan

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, osx-elcapitan, safari10

I installed updates on El Capitan OS X to get Safari 10. Per [webdriver-support-in-safari-10](https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10) - "Safari’s driver is launchable via the /usr/bin/safaridriver executable, and most client libraries provided by Selenium will automatically launch the driver this way without further configuration."

Since the Java client still needs to instantiate a flavor of WebDriver, I tried the following -

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
capabilities.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY, new SafariOptions());
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
```

instead of

```
driver = new SafariDriver();
```

but I run into the following error - `org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException`. I see

```
ps -ef | grep safari
501  1956   814   0  5:12PM ttys003    0:00.02 /usr/bin/safaridriver -p 0
```

I also checked the "Addendum" at the end of their post -

```
launchctl list | grep webdriverd
1498    0   com.apple.webdriverd
```

Has anyone been able to get it to work with Java?

Answer (score 0):

Update to `Safari 10.0.2 beta 2` from the Apple developer channel. For me, it didn't work with `10.0.1` and did work with `10.0.2 beta 2`.